# Mule: Thread count under load with doThreading="false"

Tags: multithreading, mule

we have a mule app with HTTP inbound endpoint and I'm trying to figure out how to control the thread count under load. As an experiment I have added the following configuration:

```
<core:configuration>
    <core:default-threading-profile doThreading="false" maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="RUN"/>
</core:configuration>
```

Under load I'm seeing the thread count peak at over 1000 threads. Am not sure why this is the case give the maxThreadsActive setting and the doThreading="false". Reading about poolExhaustedAction="RUN", I would expect the listener thread to block while processing inbound requests rather than spawn new ones, and finally reject the connection if its backlog queue is full. I never see rejected client connections.

Does Mule maintain a separate thread pool for each inbound endpoint in the app (sorry if this is in the documentation)? Even if so, don't think it helps explain what I'm seeing.

Any help appreciated. We are running a number of mule apps in one container and I'd like to control the total number of threads.

Thanks, Alfie.

Comment: How many HTTP connector do you have? Do you use both inbound and outbound HTTP endpoints?

Comment: Hi, I have a single HTTP inbound endpoint and two vm endpoints. The flow on the HTTP inbound endpoint uses all/processor-chain to invoke the two vm endpoints (one-way). These just do some processing and store data in mongo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the `doThreading` attribute on `default-threading-profile` is not enough to control Mule threading as a whole nor limit with a global cap the specific threading behaviour of transports. I reckon you're getting 500 threads for the HTTP message receiver pool and 500 for the VM message dispatcher pool.

I strongly suggest you reading about tuning Mule: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance

My gut feel is that you need to

- configure threading on each transport (VM, HTTP), strictly specifying the pool size for receivers and dispatchers,
- select flow processing strategies that prevent Mule from spawning new threads (i.e. use `synchronous` to hog the receiver threads),
- select exchange patterns that also prevent Mule from spawning new threads (i.e. use `request-response` to piggyback the current execution thread).